# Why do I get different results with String.intern() vs. passing String object in Java?

Tags: java

I have a command line program to validate an XML against an XSD file.  One of the command line options for this program is the namespace to use, which is stored in `String namespace`.  I get a different validation result depending on whether I pass the parsed option as `namespace` or pass the call to `namespace.intern()`.  The different results mean that somewhere in the XML validator the `String` comparisons performed on namespace have different results, even though they should have the same set of ASCII values.

Is there a fundamental reason why these might produce different comparison results?

The `NamespaceFilter` class, see below, is where the namespace value is used.  This class compares `namespace` to the value found on the current element inside `startElement` and then assigns it.  `startElement` is called by the XML reader.

These are the line variations inside validateAgainstXSD:

#### `String.intern()`

`NamespaceFilter nsf = new NamespaceFilter(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(), namespace.intern());`

*Result*:
Validating uart.xml.

#### String object as is

`NamespaceFilter nsf = new NamespaceFilter(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(), namespace);`

*Result*:
Error at 4: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'fileVersion'. One of '{"myNamespace":fileVersion}' is expected.

#### Source in context

```
public static void validateAgainstXSD(File file, File schemaFile, String namespace) {

    try {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        Schema xsdScheme = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

        Validator validator = xsdScheme.newValidator();
        ErrorHandler eh = new DefaultErrorHandler();

        validator.setErrorHandler(eh);

        // Create namespace replacement filter  
        NamespaceFilter nsf = new NamespaceFilter(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(), namespace.intern());

        // Load the XML source
        SAXSource source = new SAXSource(nsf, new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file)));

        validator.validate(source, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private String requiredNamespace;

    public NamespaceFilter(XMLReader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public NamespaceFilter(XMLReader parent, String namespace) {
        this(parent);

        requiredNamespace = namespace;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri,
            String localName,
            String qName,
            Attributes atts)
            throws SAXException {

        if (!uri.equals(requiredNamespace)) {
            uri = requiredNamespace;
        }
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);

    }
}
```

Comment: If it's obvious to you, can you explain it?

Comment: Have you checked if the line `uri = requiredNamespace;` gets executed with the interned string? I suspect your problem lies here.

Comment: @Jochen The line in your comment is executed in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `endElement()` as well, with similar logic in it. Otherwise the start and end element URIs may not match. `XMLFilterImpl` is probably matching them on == rather than .equals().

Comment: Good work, thanks!  I think that must be the case for XMLFilterImpl, which seems like a bug to me.